# ThorsSQL Lib: Part 3: Layer 2

Tags: c++, mysql, c++14, library, stream

Have a working version of MySQL implementation of ThorsSQL library done.

If you want to check it out you can find the whole thing on [github ThorsSQL](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL/tree/ef508c463aded45dd1ce0605a907f41f589b76b4).

This is a follow on to previous code Reviews:
[Part 3: Layer 1](/q/158007/507)
[Part 2](/q/94901/507)
[Part 1](/q/94899/507)

The [documentation for these classes is here](https://github.com/Loki-Astari/ThorsSQL/tree/ef508c463aded45dd1ce0605a907f41f589b76b4/src/MySQL/ReadMe.md):

### Part 3 (Layer 2): The MySQL Implementation

MySQL uses a package based protocol. Each request/response message is wrapped in a set of packages. These packages are numbered and sized to allow validation and some basic error checking of communication between the client and server. The class PackageBuffer implements the PackageStream interface; but it is used to wrap a Layer 1 stream thus hiding the packages from the next layer and still exposing a simple stream like interface.

```
Class:
==========
PackageBuffer:    PackageStream

Interface:
==========
PackageStream
```

It should be noted that the implementation of this layer is currently very basic. One of the improvement points is implementing a more efficient version of this package stream.

#### PackageBuffer.h

```
#ifndef THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_PACKAGE_BUFFER_H
#define THORS_ANVIL_MYSQL_PACKAGE_BUFFER_H

#include "PackageStream.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstddef>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

template<typename T>
class PackageBuffer: public PackageStream
{
    T&                  stream;
    std::size_t         readCurrentPacketSize;
    std::size_t         readCurrentPacketPosition;
    unsigned char       currentPacketSequenceID;
    bool                hasMore;
    bool                flushed;
    std::vector<char>   sendBuffer;

    private:
        void nextPacket();
        void writePackageHeader(std::size_t size);
        void writeStream(char const* buffer, std::size_t len);

    public:
        PackageBuffer(T& stream, bool flushed = false);
        virtual void        read(char* buffer, std::size_t len)         override;
        virtual void        write(char const* buffer, std::size_t len)  override;
        virtual bool        isEmpty()                                   override;
        virtual void        startNewConversation()                      override;
        virtual void        flush()                                     override;
        virtual void        drop()                                      override;
        virtual void        reset()                                     override;
        virtual std::string readRemainingData()                         override;
};

    }
}

#ifndef COVERAGE_MySQL
#include "PackageBuffer.tpp"
#endif

#endif
```

#### PackageBuffer.tpp

```
#include "ThorSQL/SQLUtil.h"
#include <iomanip>

namespace ThorsAnvil
{
    namespace MySQL
    {

template<typename T>
PackageBuffer<T>::PackageBuffer(T& stream, bool flushed)
    : stream(stream)
    , readCurrentPacketSize(0)
    , readCurrentPacketPosition(0)
    , currentPacketSequenceID(-1)
    , hasMore(true)
    , flushed(flushed)
{
    sendBuffer.reserve(0xFFFFFF/*16MByte*/);
}

template<typename T>
inline void PackageBuffer<T>::read(char* buffer, std::size_t len)
{
    std::size_t retrieved = 0;
    do
    {
        std::size_t remaining      = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
        std::size_t getFromPacket  = std::min((len - retrieved), remaining);
        stream.read(buffer + retrieved, getFromPacket);
        retrieved                   += getFromPacket;
        readCurrentPacketPosition   += getFromPacket;
        if (retrieved != len && remaining == 0)
        {   nextPacket();
        }
    }
    while (len != retrieved);
}

template<typename T>
bool PackageBuffer<T>::isEmpty()
{
    long remaining      = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
    if ((remaining == 0) && hasMore)
    {
        nextPacket();
        remaining      = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
    }
    return remaining == 0;
}

template<typename T>
std::string PackageBuffer<T>::readRemainingData()
{
    std::string dst;
    do
    {
        long retrieved  = dst.size();
        long remaining  = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
        dst.resize(retrieved + remaining);
        read(&dst[retrieved], remaining);
        if (hasMore)
        {
            nextPacket();
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    while (true);

    return dst;
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::nextPacket()
{
    if (!hasMore)
    {
        throw std::domain_error(
                errorMsg("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::PackageBuffer::nextPacket: ",
                         "No more data expected from server"
              ));
    }
    readCurrentPacketSize       = 0;
    readCurrentPacketPosition   = 0;
    currentPacketSequenceID++;

    std::uint32_t    packetBufferSize = 0;
    // TODO FIX only works on little endian
    stream.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&packetBufferSize), 3);
    readCurrentPacketSize   = packetBufferSize;


    char actualSequenceID;
    stream.read(&actualSequenceID, 1);

    if (currentPacketSequenceID != actualSequenceID)
    {
        throw std::domain_error(
                errorMsg("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::PackageBuffer::nextPacket: ",
                         "currentPacketSequenceID(", currentPacketSequenceID, ")",
                         " != actual sequence on input stream(",  actualSequenceID, ")"
              ));
    }

    hasMore = readCurrentPacketSize == 0xFFFFFF;
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::startNewConversation()
{
    currentPacketSequenceID = -1;
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::write(char const* buffer, std::size_t len)
{
    if (flushed)
    {
        throw std::domain_error(
                bugReport("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::PackageBuffer::write: ",
                         "Writting to a flushed buffer"
              ));
    }
    std::size_t   currentSize = sendBuffer.size();
    if (currentSize + len >= 0xFFFFFF)
    {
        std::size_t   available   = 0xFFFFFF - currentSize;
        writePackageHeader(0xFFFFFF);
        writeStream(&sendBuffer[0], currentSize);
        writeStream(buffer, available);
        sendBuffer.clear();

        buffer  += available;
        len     -= available;

        while (len > 0xFFFFFF)
        {
            writePackageHeader(0xFFFFFF);
            writeStream(buffer, 0xFFFFFF);

            buffer  += 0xFFFFFF;
            len     -= 0xFFFFFF;
        }
    }
    sendBuffer.insert(sendBuffer.end(), buffer, buffer + len);
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::flush()
{
    if (flushed)
    {
        throw std::domain_error(
                bugReport("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::PackageBuffer<T>::flush: ",
                          "Already flushed"
              ));
    }
    flushed = true;
    std::size_t   currentSize = sendBuffer.size();

    writePackageHeader(currentSize);
    writeStream(&sendBuffer[0], currentSize);
    sendBuffer.clear();
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::drop()
{
    std::size_t dataLeft;
    std::vector<char>   drop;
    do
    {
        std::size_t readDataAvailable = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
        drop.resize(readDataAvailable);
        read(&drop[0], readDataAvailable);

        dataLeft    = 0;
        if (hasMore)
        {
            nextPacket();
            dataLeft = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
        }
    }
    while (dataLeft != 0);
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::reset()
{
    std::size_t readDataAvailable = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
    if (readDataAvailable == 0 && hasMore)
    {
        nextPacket();
        readDataAvailable = readCurrentPacketSize - readCurrentPacketPosition;
    }
    if (readDataAvailable != 0)
    {
        std::stringstream  extraData;
        for (std::size_t loop=0; loop < readDataAvailable; ++loop)
        {
            char x;
            read(&x, 1);
            extraData << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << static_cast<int>(x) << "(" << x << ") ";
        }
        throw std::domain_error(
                bugReport("ThorsAnvil::MySQL::PackageBuffer<T>::reset: ",
                          "reset() before message was read:",
                          extraData.str()
              ));
    }

    flushed     = false;
    hasMore     = true; // Will allow us to start reading the next packet
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::writePackageHeader(std::size_t size)
{
    ++currentPacketSequenceID;
    stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&size), 3);
    stream.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&currentPacketSequenceID), 1);
}

template<typename T>
void PackageBuffer<T>::writeStream(char const* buffer, std::size_t len)
{
    stream.write(buffer, len);
}

    }
}
```